# How to handle many-to-many relationship in Hibernate with non-primary key?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, many-to-many

I have two objects - Role and Privilege. They have a many-to-many relationship. The code of each object is shown below.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.NaturalId;

@Entity
@Table(name = "rml_privilege")
public class RmlPrivilege extends RmlBase implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6810028565979325754L;

    public static final String ATTR_NAME = "name";


    @Column(name="name",nullable=false,unique=true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String privilege) {
        this.name = privilege;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

This is the RmlRole file.

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "rml_role")
public class RmlRole extends RmlBase {

    public final static String ATTR_ORG = "org.id";

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "organization")
    private RmlOrganization organization;

    //TODO: In case of LAZY loading, recieve an error
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "rml_role_privilege", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "role", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "privilege", referencedColumnName = "name") })
    Set<RmlPrivilege> privileges;

    public RmlOrganization getOrganization() {
        return organization;
    }

    public void setOrganization(RmlOrganization organization) {
        this.organization = organization;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Set<RmlPrivilege> getPrivileges() {
        return privileges;
    }

    public void setPrivileges(Set<RmlPrivilege> privileges) {
        this.privileges = privileges;
    }

}
```

When I try to get the RmlRole object, I end up getting the "privileges' variable to be blank. I expect the privilege object set to be prepared. I am doing it wrong somewhere but unable to identify.

My Hibernate version: 5
Java 1.8
Spring Boot application

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: (is there an "id"(unique or PK) property on `RmlBase`?, if yes, your join table looks ok!), but, why do you expect privileges "not blank"? ...are there any entries in `rml_role_privilege` table??

Comment: Yes there are entries in the table. I need to join the privileges and roles using this table.